# A positive result in if or Else?

Tags: python, coding-style, if-statement

This is coding style based, was wondering if it's better to put a positive outcome from an if/else decision in the if or else block. For example is:

```
    yes_no = object.get() #Response will be 'yes' or 'no'
    if yes_no == 'yes':
        yes response
    else:
        no response
```

better than:

```
    yes_no = object.get() #Response will be 'yes' or 'no'
    if yes_no != 'yes':
        no response
    else:
        yes response
```

As far as I can tell there's no difference, as they both look for a 'yes' and output a yes response, but is there any sort of styling that people follow or find easier to read?

I'm using python, but since if/else is everywhere I guess other languages are relevant also.

EDIT: Replaced passes with no response, as were unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you need the pass statement at all? Is it just the specifics of this example - or something you'd actually do? The last two lines of the first example are completely extrenuous.

Comment: Why is this an important thing to worry about?  Isn't simple "clarity" pretty easy to establish?  What problem do you have?  Are there other folks arguing with you?  Is there a performance problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have anything that actually looks like this, but I don't really want to have to edit and rearrange large sections of code in order to keep up with style rules I didn't know when writing.  I hope the no/yes response clarifies it better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that most depends on what the programmer wants to highlight. The IF condition should be either:

- the most probable
- the simplest
- the one which leads to less calculation
- the more readable
- ...

Personally I always try to avoid this:

```
if condition:
    ... tons of code ...
else:
    ... one line of code ...
```

Answer (score 2):

- Most of the time it's cleaner to avoid double negative (like `!is_no`)
- Put early out statements first, whatever the condition is:

  ```
  if(!a): 
      return
  else:
      long 
      sequence
      of
      statements
  ```

Answer (score 1):

That strictly depends on your program's logic. If it makes sense to make a "positive" condition, then make it a positive condition. If it's a negative "condition", then make it a negative condition. There are no set rules of style when it comes to conditions of either type, or at least not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Best advice I could give you is do what reads best in your code and don't bother with code paths that don't add anything. I would rework your code as:

```
yes_no = object.get() #Response will be 'yes' or 'no'
    if yes_no == 'yes':
        yes response
```

If there's no action for the `no` condition there's no reason to check for it. I'd also rework the "get" to make it more obvious why it is returning a yes or no response. As it is, `object.get()` is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

If your method only returns one of two values, have it `return True` or `return False`, not arbitrary strings. And you should probably rename it so the method name means something.

Then you can do

```
if object.get():
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

or

```
if not object.get():
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

omitting the `else` if only one case actually leads to a response.